# Dockerfile: How do I reflect the right path?

Tags: docker

I keep having an issue where I get the error: `Cannot find module '/mfa/main.js'`.

However, the `main.js` is inside of `/mfa/dist/apps/api`

This is the latest configuration of Dockerfile I have:

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /mfa/

COPY package.json .
COPY decorate-angular-cli.js .
COPY yarn.lock .

# Configure NPM with the group access token
ENV GROUP_NPM_TOKEN="asdfghjkiuy"
RUN npm config set @my-web:registry http://git.hoosiers.com/api/v4/packages/npm
RUN npm config set //git.hoosiers.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=${GROUP_NPM_TOKEN}
RUN npm config set //git.hoosiers.com/api/v4/packages/projects/:_authToken=${GROUP_NPM_TOKEN}

RUN yarn add typescript

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
COPY ./dist .

CMD ["node", "apps/api/main.js"]
```

So now `docker run <image-hash>` runs just fine, but when I attempt `docker-compose up` is when I once again get `Cannot find module '/mfa/main.js'`.

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  web-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: mostly-failed-apps.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have difine your WORKDIR is /mfa and you execute your main.js in apps/api/main.js

And tip for copy it's not mandatory to write /mfa/ you can just write dot (.) because your in WORKDIR

```
`
FROM node:14
# Go on /mfa if is dosen't exist WORKDIR create it and go in
WORKDIR /mfa/

# Copy of package.json where we are so we are with the dot so in /mfa/ it's the same for all copy
COPY package.json .
COPY decorate-angular-cli.js .
COPY yarn.lock .

# Configure NPM with the group access token
ENV GROUP_NPM_TOKEN="token"
RUN npm config set @my-web:registry http://git.hoosiers.com/api/v4/packages/npm
RUN npm config set //git.hoosiers.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=${GROUP_NPM_TOKEN}
RUN npm config set //git.hoosiers.com/api/v4/packages/projects/:_authToken=${GROUP_NPM_TOKEN}

RUN yarn add typescript

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
COPY ./dist .

# You have create your docker with /mfa/ so you need to excute it in /mfa/
CMD ["node", "/mfa/dist/apps/api/main.js"]
`
```

Comment: @Wollau, are you suggesting that my `WORDIR` should be `apps/api/`?

Comment: normaly your WORKDIR is in /mfa and after your path. So I think /mfa/dist/apps/api

Comment: @Wollau, what does the `COPY` line need to indicate?

Comment: And I think "RUN mkdir -p /mfa" it's useless "WORKDIR /mfa" create /mfa if it's dosen't exist

Comment: @Wollau, for `RUN` I suspected it was useless because I have never used it before. Now for `COPY`, should it be `COPY ./ /mfa/dist/apps/api`?

Comment: Can you paste your change please ?

Comment: I don't understand you want to copy what where ?

Comment: @Wollau, the above file is now the most current one. Don't I need to run a `COPY` before `CMD`?

Comment: "WORKDIR /mfa/" but when your execute your code "CMD ["node", "/mfa/apps/api/main.js"]" you need to add /mfa/ because now your in a docker in /mfa/

Comment: so I don't need `COPY ./ /mfa/dist/apps/api`?

Comment: I have update my Answer with code and explanation, if you don't understand something tell me

Comment: @Wollau, even with your answer I am still getting, `Cannot find module '/mfa/dist/apps/api/main.js'` because now there is no `dist/` in that image. When I made a slight change to `CMD` like so: `CMD ["node", "/mfa/apps/api/main.js"]` I go back to seeing `Cannot find module '/mfa/main.js'`.

Comment: In your code you have a dist ? and in your dist you have a apps/api/main.js ?

Comment: @Wollau, check out my original post, I updated it with everything I have done so far.

Comment: @Wollau, I needed to do a `docker-compose up --build`.

Comment: @Daniel Yes I see, but I don't know what is your project. What kind of file do you have /app/ ?

Comment: In your dockerfile you need to exercute the command for build your application for create the ./dist

Comment: And when you change something on your dockefile you need to create a new build (docker built -t NAME_OF_YOUR_IMAGE) because if you just RUN you RUN the last image with no change